# Is there a tool that could help me use my Linux scripts in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, bash, script

I am new here. I would like to know if there is a tool that would help me use my Linux scripts in Windows? I am more comfortable with Linux commands than Windows. I also tried to download a software called FireCMD but it didn't work for me. I hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: You could refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581506/how-to-run-linux-shell-script-on-windows-environment) given on Stack overflow.

Comment: See also: [Is there a better, more UNIX-like command line shell for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/422163/is-there-a-better-more-unix-like-command-line-shell-for-windows) and [Linux/Unix in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/117688/linux-unix-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) and comes with a console emulator ten times as awesome as Windows' built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It will provide a complete set of *nix tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki), [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), or various alternatives like that?  Cygwin is a fairly fully featured emulator, Gow and MinGW are more minimalistic.